# Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment CSHTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-core, razor

In a razor file .cshtml , I have declared a variable like this

```
@{ string myVariable = "";}
```

then
I have used this variable in order to have the value of an input :

```
<input id ="myInput"/>
<script>
'@myVariable' = $('#myInput').val();
</script>
```

but get `==> Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to set value of `myVariable` with `$('#myInput').val()`.You can firstly refer to the [official link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/razor?view=aspnetcore-5.0).`@{ string myVariable = "";}` means `myVariable`  is a c# variable.So you cannot set a c# varilable with js `'@myVariable' = $('#myInput').val();`.You can use a js variable.Here is a demo.

View:

```
<input id="myInput" onblur="setValue()"/>
<script>
        var myVariable;
        function setValue(){
            myVariable = $('#myInput').val();
            alert(myVariable);
        }
</script>
```

result:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

In order to set a value, use:

```
$("#myInput").val("value");
```

so you replace the `value` with your razor variable directly, giving:

```
$("#myInput").val("@myVariable")
```

Be advised that if your `myVariable` is String.Empty (`""`) then the rendered html would be

```
$("#myInput").val("");
```

so would clear / appear to not set the input.

---

If you look the *rendered* html that your view provides, your original code would be:

```
'' = $("#myInput").val();
```

and taking that as javascript directly you can see that you can't assign a value to a variable named `''`.  Or if your myVariable wasn't empty string it would appear as:

```
'myValue' = ...
```

which also isn't valid javascript.

---

Note that you don't need javascript/jquery to set a value, you can use the Razor variable directly within the html:

```
<input id="myInput" type="text" value="@myVariable">
```